# How to select an input element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

A page contains a form with element

```
<input type="submit" class="button primary" value="Submit" accesskey="s">
```

I attempted all the next options to select that button

```
//driver.findElement((By.cssSelector("//*@id='QuickReply']/div[2]/input[2]"))).submit(); //this path is from firebug
//driver.findElement(By.className("button.primary")).submit();
driver.findElement(By.tagName("form")).submit();
```

But I get errors with those selects. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting..need to share it...:)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
"//input[@class='button primary']" or "//input[@value='Submit']"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try using `.click()` instead of `.submit()` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button.primary[value='Submit']")).click();
```

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work...is there any exception??